# JQuery: What is a proper way to keep the scope of an object when different functions are called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a general question as the title states.  I am just not sure if what I am doing is the proper way or perhaps there is an easier way to keep the scope of an object.

I have here an example just to illustrate what I am working with.  You can see I am passing the "this" object to the function via a parameter however is this the only way to do it?  Is there a way I don't need to pass the parameter.

Please note that the criteria is there is no identifying class/ids on the forms.

http://jsfiddle.net/TmaHs/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example, there are easier ways :

```
$("form select").on('change', changeText);

function changeText(e) { //the event is still available
    $("input", e.target.form).val("Changed!"); //so is the target and the form
}
```

will do the same. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TmaHs/2/)

As for more complex functions, passing an element to the function is usually not a problem, and in my opinion it's better than using globals.

Comment: Thank you for this! Just having trouble understanding this line-> e.target.form.  Does that mean if I wanted something different I could say something like -> e.target.div if there was a div wrapper?

Comment: Nope, not really. In javascript `e.target` is the target element, in this case it's the `select` element that was changed. Every form element has the parent form attached as just `element.form`, so that gets you the parent form for any form element like `input`, `select` etc, but it does'nt necessarily work that way for other elements like div wrappers, it's for forms only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard bind function to explicitly set the context

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Or the similar equivalent in jquery if it has one (I'm not sure about this)

Answer (score 0):

That's a valid way of doing it - an alternative is to declare the variable in a higher scope, assign it in the first function, and reference it without the need to use arguments in the second function.

See [this edit to your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/TmaHs/1/) for example.

Comment: Thanks for this as this is also a viable option.

Answer (score -1):

You could work with the window object, by declaring the variable out of score, then setting the window-object of it.

```
$("form select").change(function() {
    window.thisObj = $(this).parent("form");
    changeText(); 
});

function changeText() {
    window.thisObj.find("input").val("Changed!");   
}
```

​
But the way you did it is the proper one, working with a window-object should always be avoided.

Comment: Why use the window object at all? Your code would work fine if you remove `window` as `thisObj` is declared in the outer scope, and therefore works when called in function context as well as global, without polluting global namespace.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after looking at your fiddle. What I was trying to convey was to have access to the variable without declaring it in a higher scope. My mistake, I will edit it correctly. Thanks for noticing! :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong in that approach... Its perfectly fine :)

BUT, if you still want to know the other way, then there are many...
I will post couple of them over here...

1) Retrieve all the values that you need in your selector function, and pass them to the function.

```
$("form select").change(function() {
    var val1 = $("selector1").val();
    var val1 = $("selector2").val();
    var val1 = $("selector3").val();

   changeText(val1,val2,val3); 
});

function changeText(val1,val2,val3) {
// your operation
}
```

2) Add the required values to an array, and pass that array to your target function.

```
var targetArray = new Array();
    $("form select").change(function() {
       targetArray[0]=//your val1
       targetArray[1]=//your val2
       targetArray[2]=//your val3

       changeText(targetArray); 
    });

    function changeText(arr) {
    // your operation
    }
​
```

Comment: your second example does not make much sense, did you mean to declare `targetArray` in the scope of the change handler instead?

Comment: Well, honestly speaking I didn't think that much while posting this example.. :) BUT, now I would say that, I just declared that out of that handler just to avoid re initializing the same targetArray.
Now I think It would have been better if I had declared that in the same score as of the handler, since it will completely erase the previous values... :)

Comment: I generally avoid `new Array()` - using `[]` instead is [much more performant](http://jsperf.com/literal-vs-constructor-array) and quicker to type too! :)

Comment: @AdityaParab `targetArray` is scoped higher than both the handler and `changeText` so why would you even bother passing it to `changeText`?

Comment: @jbabey Stupid silly mistakes... :) Thanks for pointing that out :) - Down vote deserved :D